# rails group collection by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm have a few collections in a controller like so:

```
def show
  @cave = Cave.includes(cubs: :mamabear).where(id: params[:id]).first
  @cubs = @cave.cubs
  @papabear = Papabear.first
  @dens = Den.where(papabear_id: @papabear.id)
end
```

and now I'm trying to sort cubs by dens so I can display the cubs with

```
@dens.each do |d| 
  d.cubs
end
```

so I wrote the following:

```
def show
....
  @dens.each do |den|
    den.cubs = []  ## < --- Den does not have an association with Cub ##
    @cubs.each do |cub|
      den.cubs << cub if cub.mamabear.den_id == den.id
    end
  end

  #reject dens if they don't have cubs
  @dens = @dens.reject { |den| den.cubs.all?(&:blank?) }

end
```

But now I'm getting an undefined method 'cubs for Den' error because Den doesn't have an association with Cub. How do I assign an array of Cubs to each Den without an association?

Comment: you cannot acheive this using `den.cubs`. you are initializing array to  `den.cubs`  but you cannot do that for den as that is active record object , you need something to make a hash and insert into array each time.Array should be initialize out side the den loop, use that array in the loop on show page.

Comment: @Athar can you point me to an example please?

Comment: sure i will try to replicate your case in the answer below. may be some mistakes. but we can always improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: I would create a standard association of Cubs for den. Probably a standard has_many On dens, so each cub has a den_id.

You're messing about re-inventing the wheel, otherwise.

2: you'll probably find that the undefined method is 'cubs=' as opposed to 'cubs'. It's an important distinction as it says what the code is doing when the error is thrown.

3: if you really want to ignore point 1 and make your own which fills an arbitrary attribute from the controller, you can add this to the Den model.

```
attr_accessor :cubs
```

Comment: I will re-iterate, if you're using ActiveRecord models, building associations after retrieving the record instead of storing the association in your database is a bad idea. Having re-read the code, you can probably do this with 'belongs_to :den, through: mama_bear'

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The actual models are less related than the names suggest, and I only needed to group them like this in this single controller action without having to persist the association in the database. Attr accessor works well enough for this one-off scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Association is the best way to handle such scenarios if you want to fetch those `cubs` belonging to `den` at multiple places. if you dont want to implement association. you can try this solution

```
@den_cubs = []
@dens.each do |den|
  cub_for_den= {}  #here we are initializing hash each time for new den
  @cubs.each do |cub|
    cub_for_den[cub.id] = cub if cub.mamabear.den_id == den.id
  end
  @den_cubs << cub_for_den #put the hash in array
end

@den_cubs = @den_cubs.reject { |dc| dc.blank? }
```

on the show page you can do this

```
@den_cubs.each do |dc|
  dc.each do |k,v|
    # now here you can display all attributes for the cubs
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Athar, but simply adding attr_accessor to the model worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a "has many through"-association in regards to cubs -> dens and dens -> cubs?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Examples:

```
class Den
  has_many :mamabears
  has_many :cubs, through: :mamabears
end

class Cup
  belongs_to :mamabear
  has_one :den, through: :mamabear
end
```

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
den.cups #=> [<Cup ...>]
cup.den #=> <Den ...>
```